# MongoDB $$ROOT not working in aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

The following query is not working:

```
db.getCollection('contracts').aggregate([
  {$sort: {startDate: -1}},
  {$group: {
   _id:"$propertyId",
   lastDocument: {$last: "$$ROOT"}
  } }
])
```

I want to get the whole document in the `lastDocument` property.
If I use `$$ROOT.<field>` it does work.

How can I get the whole document as result of the aggregation?

EDIT2: I've tried running this on my local mongodb instance and it works, but it doesn't when I run the query on the MongoDb Atlas Cloud version.

EDIT: Added images to show the error.

**Working**
[image]

**Not Working**
[image]

Comment: `propertyId` should prefix with `$` sign. Although `$last` is working for me.

Comment: It was a typo on my side, it's fixed. Still, when I use just $$ROOT, the query throws an error, on both Robo3T and in MongoDB atlas. If I use just a property of $$ROOT, such as $ROOT._id, then it works.

I want to get the whole document, not just the id of it.

Comment: What is the error? What is your version?

Comment: I've added some images showing the issue. I'm using MongoDB Atlas, the version is Version 4.0.10.